# Troubles with ownership and borrowing, and sharing instance across multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to learn Rust through a toy project called [workers](https://github.com/endel/workers). I am trying to run `task.perform()` [inside a thread pool](https://github.com/endel/workers/blob/c8a3f5ffe7307acc5be4330eb4caca3dcb64fe33/src/lib.rs#L50-L53).

The problem:

```
    Compiling workers v0.1.0 (file:///Users/endel/Projects/rust/workers)
src/lib.rs:45:21: 45:32 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
src/lib.rs:45     let next = self.next_task();
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:45:16: 45:20 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the expression at 45:15...
src/lib.rs:45     let next = self.next_task();
                             ^~~~
src/lib.rs:45:16: 45:20 note: ...so that auto-reference is valid at the time of borrow
src/lib.rs:45     let next = self.next_task();
                             ^~~~
src/lib.rs:45:16: 45:32 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the method call at 45:15...
src/lib.rs:45     let next = self.next_task();
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:45:16: 45:20 note: ...so that method receiver is valid for the method call
src/lib.rs:45     let next = self.next_task();
                             ^~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I've asked for help in the #rust IRC channel and they suggested to use `Box<Task>` (owned) instead of `&Box<Task>` (borrowed), in order to copy the task during the `move || {}` statement, I suppose.

Is this a viable solution? There is any other? I've tried changing the `Worker` impl methods from `&self` to `self`, but other problems start to pop out, and I can't get an owned `Box<Task>` for my `work` method.

Here is a simplified version in the [playgound](http://is.gd/Cr4qja) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Please produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem. Ideally, make it run on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/). Include that code *in your question*, else it risks being closed. Emphasis on the **M**; it's not appreciated to post hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster, I've added a playground link in the question, is it ok?

Comment: @Endel: much better thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked about it on #rust IRC channel, and tomaka [answered me](http://is.gd/vfIWGj).

Basically:

- Changed `&Box<Task>` to `Box<Task>`
- `get_task_by_name` now removes an element from the `Vec`
- the Vec is now inside a Mutex so that you can modify it